# Check if the input day is Monday with moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Well, I want to check if a day of date is Monday like:

```
var myDate = new Date();
moment(myDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY').dayIs('monday')
```

In my country the first day of week is Monday, so, really I want check if the input date is begin of week.

I try using `moment(myDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY').startOf('isoweek')` but, this don't work for me.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/weekday/) - Moment.js has a locale setting which should solve this for you;

> Day of Week (Locale Aware) 2.1.0+
>
> `moment().weekday(Number);`
>
> `moment().weekday(); // Number`
>
> Gets or sets the day of the week according to the locale.
>
> If the locale assigns Monday as the first day of the week, moment().weekday(0) will be Monday. If Sunday is the first day of the week, moment().weekday(0) will be Sunday.

[Here you can see how to set the locale](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/getting-locale/);

`moment.locale('en'); // set to english`