# how to collect date that will fall on a specific day input

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I just want to ask if you have an idea on how to get the collection of date.

Sample:

```
Sunday = ['12/03/2017','12/10/2017','12/17/2017','12/24/2017','12/31/2017'....];
```

It collected all the date that will fall on Sunday.

Is there a function in `javascript` or `php` that could help me or should I do it manually?

Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: For the current month only?

Comment: why downvote? instead of saying the solution.

Answer (score 0):

For **JAVASCRIPT** Use Moment.js

Your question is related to this post
[Check if the input day is Monday with moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41638428/check-if-the-input-day-is-monday-with-moment-js)

```
moment(date).weekday(1)
```

For **PHP** Use function `date($format, $timestamp)` then use format `l (lowercase 'L')` A full textual representation of the day of the week

```
if(date('l', $date) == 'Sunday'){};
```

See full documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

In php

I think first select minimum & maximum date from which you want to start your collection.
E.g:

```
$s = '2017-01-01';
$e='2017-10-01';
```

Convert this to time

```
$stime = strtotime($s); 
$etime=strtotime($e);
```

Get first sunday

```
$sunday = strtotime('next sunday', $stime); 

$format = 'Y-m-d';
```

Initialise array with first Sunday.

```
$sun=array(date($format, $sunday));
```

Use while loop to check and make an array of Sunday's dates

```
while($sunday<$etime){
$sunday=strtotime('next sunday', $sunday);
array_push($sun, date($format, $sunday));
}

Print_r($sun);
```

Hope it'll help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Another option with php is to use 2 [datetimes](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and loop though all the sundays between them. You can use [modify](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) to set your range and [format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) to specify the format of the date.

For example:

```
$dayStart = new DateTime('12/03/2017');
$dayEnd = new DateTime();
$dayEnd->modify("+1 month");
$sundays = [];

for ($dayCurrent = $dayStart; $dayCurrent <=$dayEnd; $dayCurrent->modify('next sunday')) {
    array_push($sundays, $dayCurrent->format('m/d/Y'));
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/8oJsr)